# Dropdown sub menu disappear very early on IE10 not able to hover over submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Client site is http://173.254.106.187/gurianWP/. nav menu drop down working fine on all browser but on IE 10 can't able to hover over submenu it disappear very early. client using SR menu wordpress plugin, but i know its an IE rendering issue because href element have lost it scope in selected area one can check easily on IE the above link.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for the sub menu here? For people who don't like clicking on links ( like myself ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it can be fixed by adding a **transparent background** on your li in your css

```
.main-navigation-srm li{ background:rgba(0,0,0,0);}
```

Comment: thanks bro, can you please how background property work for link scope. i appreciate you thanks again

Comment: background-color (and by extension background) can take various values : predefined colors (like red, yellow...), hex (like #123456), rgb (with values for Red Green Blue, like rgb(200,124,5)), or rgba (same as rgb but with one more value for Alpha, the last one, between 0 and 1, where 0 is transparent, and 1 is opaque)

Comment: I know background css property i am sorry i think i asked in wrong manner  my question was how transparent background color work for that issue.

Comment: IE10 considers rgba as a solid color and by the way considers it as a full relevant content in the block element (li here). You can also do the trick with a transparent png used as background image